# checkbox not showing checked i UI after updating status using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have some checkbox on a dialog box and i am checking data availability from database.If checkbox value is 1 then it should be checked and if not 1 then should not be checked.

I have multiple list for which this dialog box is opening and on every opening checkbox has to be reset.

Now my problem is when i have value in database it showing checked its Ok and when i am not geting value 1 then it clear checked. also ok but now i again opened dialog for having value 1 in this case checkbox is not checked but in html code it have an attribute checked.
my code is:

```
if (item.status) {
    if (item.cma == '1') {
        $('#cma').attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        $('#cma').removeAttr('checked');
    }
} else {
    $('#cma').removeAttr('checked');
}
```

problem occurring when script going through `item.status=false` case.
I can't `CTR+F5` because its is in dialog box.
Please help me. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you also add your initial `html` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the checked value with prop instead of attr:

```
$('#cma').prop('checked',true);
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-value

Comment: i think ` $('#cma').attr('checked',true);`   not 'true'

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
if (item.status) {
    if (item.cma == '1') {
        $('#cma').attr('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('#cma').attr('checked',false);
    }
} else {
    $('#cma').attr('checked',false);
}
```